# rebol getting the line in an area by the caret position

Tags: rebol

How do I get the line in an area where the carret is positionned ?
For example, by putting the caret on line 0816 (anywhere on the line), how do i get the line "0816 LEANYER NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE" ?
thanks

```
rebol []

sample-data: [
"0810 TIWI NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0811 WAGAMAN NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0812 WANGURI NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0813 CASUARINA NT PO Boxes CASUARINA"
"0814 ANULA NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0815 KARAMA NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0816 LEANYER NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0817 MALAK NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0818 MARRARA NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0819 SANDERSON NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0820 WULAGI NT DARWIN DELIVERY CENTRE"
"0821 SANDERSON NT PO Boxes SANDERSON"
"0822 NIGHTCLIFF NT PO Boxes NIGHTCLIFF"
"0823 NIGHTCLIFF NT PO Boxes NIGHTCLIFF"
"0824 NIGHTCLIFF NT PO Boxes NIGHTCLIFF"
"0825 NIGHTCLIFF NT PO Boxes NIGHTCLIFF"
]


gui: layout [
b1: backcolor yellow
style fld field 300
across
c1: crit1: fld "hello"
return
ab: area 790x300 font-size 18 wrap []
return

button "Start" [       
        for counter 1 16 1 [ 
         append ab/text reduce [sample-data/(counter) newline]
         ]
         show ab
         ]

button "Quit" [quit]
]
view gui
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, nice to see another Rebol programmer here.  *(Out of the shadows, guys!  :-))*  In this case, instead of `for counter 1 16 1` you could have written `repeat counter length? sample-data`.  Or even `foreach data sample-data [append ab/text reduce [data newline]]`.  Then there's `repend ab/text [data newline]`...sky's the limit.  Anyway, we always like to discuss these things, so if you'd like come join [our StackOverflow chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) and we can talk about those issues and more...

Comment: Thanks, this gives me new hints at programming. I am new in rebol so it takes time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click into a text or area face, the index into the text there is placed into system/view/caret.  So, once the cursor is visible in your area face, you can then grab this caret index, and then calculate which line it is on.

However, unless you want users to edit the area face, I would have thought using a list face would be somewhat easier to use.

Here's some working code - add this button

```
button "Find" [
    use [ before cnt ][
        if all [ 
            system/view/caret 
            find ab/text system/view/caret
            before: copy/part ab/text find ab/text system/view/caret
        ][
            parse/all before [ (cnt: 1 ) some [ thru newline ( cnt: cnt + 1 ) ]]
            alert pick sample-data cnt  
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I don't think I would have found the answer by myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I don't think I would have found the answer by myself. Concerning the area face, I asked myself the question, if it would not have been better to use a list face. The progam I have put there is just a simplified program to get a specific answer to my problem. In fact, the true program runs through a text (25000 lines) and select lines according to a criteria. Those lines can have between 20 to 430 characters. So, I was wondering if it was appropriate to have list face instead of area face, letting know that no editing has to be made on those selected lines ?

Comment: I have tested and I have noticed that you get the line from sample-data. But, in my case (just the comment above), I want to get the line directly from the area and not from the file (in your answer, you pick the line from sample-data), because the area is the result of selected lines and not the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the version you asked;

```
button "Find" [
    use [ before cnt ][
        if start: system/view/caret [
            ;find the previous newline char (if no this is the first line)
            start: either found? st: find/reverse/tail start newline [st] [head start]
            end: either found? st: find start newline [st] [tail start]
            probe copy/part start end
        ]
    ]
]
```

please accept the answer of Graham's, I just extended his version.

Comment: There should be a newline character on the last line, if not it doesn't work for the last line, or you should add additional check for that just like I did for the start

Comment: Ok I added the "last line" check and fixed the "same line" problem.